# What happens to a tailed beast if it's Jinkiurichi is killed?

Tags: naruto

What happens to a tailed beast if it's Jinkiurichi is killed while he still has the tailed beast inside of him/her?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Jinchuriki is killed then the chakra of the tailed beast disperses and after a while reforms somewhere else.

Comment: Quotes are always good or references. That way when answering, you get more upvotes on your answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

It was stated that the Bijuu will disappear from the world for a while, and then reappear at some later time.

This was first said by Kushina on the day of the Nine-tails' attack that "I'll drag him down with me to death, that will buy us some time until it revives".

It was then later reinforced on several occasions that killing a Jinchuuriki without extracting the Bijuu will make it reappear at a later time in an apparently random place.